# How to fix the bool symbol from Agda showing up as a square box with hex and decimal numbers in Emacs?

Tags: unicode, emacs, fonts, agda

I just installed the Agda Windows binary from the Wiki, but for some reason the [blackboard bold **B** symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d539/index.htm) (used by the free Agda book by Stump for booleans) shows up incorrectly. I tried changing the [font as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779351/how-to-stop-emacs-falling-back-to-rasterized-unicode-characters), but that did not work.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Could be still just font issue. DejaVu Sans Mono is the one I recommend.

Comment: No...I do not think the setting the font affects these special characters for some reason. It seems to be an Emacs issue, but I am using the one packaged with the binary directly so this is strange. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Update: It seems that it is a font issue. When I set it to plain DejaVu Sans the symbols do show up correctly. But they do not on most fonts, including DejaVu Sans Mono that you recommended. Maybe I'll try replacing them with those from [the Wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Docs.HowToSeeUnicode).

Answer (score 3):

On my computer, inside the `C:\Users\Marko\AppData\Roaming\.emacs`file I added the following Lisp code fragment:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" nil
                  (font-spec :name "DejaVu Sans"))
```

This sets DejaVu Sans as [the fallback font](http://endlessparentheses.com/manually-choose-a-fallback-font-for-unicode.html) for the missing unicode characters. With this it works for me.